# How to get date range for a specific month starting with a previous month using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm trying to build a list of "pay days" for a given month in the future knowing only when the pay days started months ago. For example:

- Starting date - When the paychecks started: 1/6/2023
- Frequency is every two weeks

So if I want to know which dates are pay days in March, I have to start at the 1/6/2023 and add two weeks until I get to March to know that the first pay day in March is 3/3/2/2023.

Then I want my final list of dates to be only those March dates of:

`(3/3/2023, 3/17/2023, 3/31/2023)`

I know I can use pandas to do something like:

`pd.date_range(starting_date, starting_date+relativedelta(months=1), freq='14d')`

but it would include every date back to 1/6/2023.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do here would be to just update the starting_date parameter to be the first pay day in the month you're interested in.

To do this, you can use this function that finds the first pay day in a given month by first finding the [difference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-between-two-dates-in-minutes-using-datetime-timedelta-method/) between your start date and the desired month.

```
# month is the number of the month (1-12) 
def get_first_pay_day_in_month(month=datetime.datetime.now().month,
                               year=datetime.datetime.now().year,
                               start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 6),
                               ):
    diff = datetime.datetime(year, month, 1) - start_date

    freq = 14

    if diff.days % freq == 0:
        print(f'Difference: {diff.days/freq} weeks')
        return datetime.datetime(year,month,1)
    else:
        print(f'Difference: {diff.days} days')
        print(f'Days: {diff.days % freq} extra')
        return datetime.datetime(year,month,1 + 14 - (diff.days % freq))
```

Then you can use this function to get the first pay day of a specific month and plug it into the date_range method.

```
from dateutil import  relativedelta

starting_date = get_first_pay_day_in_month(month=3)
pay_days = pd.date_range(starting_date, starting_date+relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1), freq='14d')

print(pay_days)
```